# How to find substring in string and create new one Swift

Tags: swift, substring

How to make this operation in Swift
1) Find substring var sub = "brother" in string var general = "hey brother"
2) Create new one from general, but only without substring, as the result need to be: "hey " 
And which method can start searching substring from end in main string

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't expect people here to just write your code for you. If you post what you've tried and the trouble you are having you are likely to get better quality responses.

Answer (score 2):

There are of course other ways to cut the string but you can definitely use this. You haven't said much about your intent with this code so give this a try. Also please keep in mind that this syntax is used in Swift 3 (if you are using Swift 2 you should work with Xcode to get the right syntax for the functions)

```
var sub = "brother"
var general = "hey brother"
if general.contains(sub) {
 general = general.replacingOccurrences(of: sub, with: "")
}
```

PS I agree that you should have provided at least some code to show that you at least tried to solve the problem on your own first!

Comment: tech4242 thank you. And sorry for my question without my example, so this is my solution: general.removeRange(general.rangeOfString(sub)!), but problem that example general string can be like this: "brother hey brother" I always need delete only last brother not first... So how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution:

```
var general = "brother hey brother"
var sub = "brother"
var index = general.rangeOfString(sub, options: .BackwardsSearch)?.startIndex

var newGeneral = general.substringToIndex(index!)
```